# Опечатка в резолюции о проверке сообщения высокого качества

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Качество сообщения о высоком качестве сообщения недостаточно высокое:

[image: высокого качество]

Необходимые исправления, я думаю, очевидны.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание! Обновил переводы.